# Integrating Orchard with existing Azure Project

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, orchardcms

I've read the docs but I'm still a bit lost on how to integrate Orchard with my existing solution.

Currently I have a Solution containing an Azure Project with a WCF Service WebRole and a Worker Role. What I want to achieve is to add another WebRole containing an Orchard powered Website + custom modules (that yet have to be written) and deploy the whole thing to Azure in one go from the Visual Studio Publish feature (ordinary publish - not web deploy). The WCF Service would listen to https://api.example.com while the website would be reachable under http://www.example.com (note no SSL here).

Is this possible and if yes, could someone provide some rough guidance?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what could possibly prevent you from doing exactly that.

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy Well, the first question would be what I need to download/repository clone to integrate a fully functional extensible Orchard site into a webrole. The website docs are anything but clear in this regard.

Comment: http://orchardproject.net/docs/Deploying-Orchard-to-Windows-Azure.ashx gives step by step instructions to do that.

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy Hmm, nowhere in that document (and I've read it before) can I see how you integrate Orchard into a VS2010 solution as a project as just another WebRole which builds and deploys along with the other projects in the solution.

Comment: You mean into an existing solution? That wasn't clear at all from your question, where you are talking about another web role and having the two communicate using WCF. Can you please update the question to explain what it is exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy Huh? I'm sorry but what else would " I have a Solution containing an Azure Project with a WCF Service WebRole and a Worker Role .." indicate?

Comment: You also said "what I want to achieve is to add another Webrole", which seems to indicate that you want to keep them separated (good), and have them communicate through WCF services (fine). I still don't understand why you want to deploy "the whole thing" to Azure in one go. I don't think you can do that, and I'm not sure I see the point. Why don't you deploy your existing solution, your new Orchard solution, and be done with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is that the typical Orchard download is loaded into VS as a Web Site Project (WSP) instead of a Web Appliation Project (WAP). Azure web roles are WAPs, not WSPs, so you have a couple of choices:

- If you're starting with a brand new Orchard site, download the Orchard source code (instead of the zip) and use the Azure solution from in there. You can either integrate your two existing roles into their Azure project, or move all the Orchard stuff over to your sln. I would think it'd be easier just to use their sln, and add your two projects to it.
- or, If you're starting from an existing Orchard site, you'll have to convert it to a WAP using techniques similar to what is outlined at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx. This will be a bit more work, as the sample is moving a WebForms site over, so you'll need to pick the MVC3 project template instead, and add all the NuGet packages in yourself, etc.

Either way, it's not trivial, but if you're lucky enough to fall into the first category above, it shouldn't take too long to do.